# Не могу написать php файл для моего MultipartEntity Android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

```
public static void executeMultipartPost(String url, String id, String field1, String field2){
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost poster = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        entity.addPart("name", new StringBody(field1));
        entity.addPart("id", new StringBody(id));
        entity.addPart("text", new StringBody(field2));
        poster.setEntity(entity );

        client.execute(poster, new ResponseHandler<Object>() {
            public Object handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();
                String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(respEntity);
                // do something with the response string
                return null;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e){
        //do something with the error
    }
}
```

это моя функция для добавление комента

проблема в том что он не добавляет

мой php файл

```
    <?php
   try{
      $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=***;dbname=***', '***', '***' );
      $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
   }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
   }

  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $page_id = $_POST["id"];
  $text_comment = $_POST["text"];

  $equery = $handler -> query("INSERT INTO `Commnets` (`name`, `page_id`, `text_comment`) VALUES ('$name', '$page_id', '$text_comment')");
  $records = array();
```

думаю проблема в php

можете ли вы мне написать правильно ?

Comment: 1. Меняйте пароль на базу; 2. Нельзя собирать запрос к базе из неэкранированных значений полей; 3. Посмотрите в лог сервера и опубликуйте ошибку, которую выдает PHP

Comment: @tutankhamun можно не менять. Там внешние подключения закрыты. Я пробовал.

Comment: @MAXOPKA Я тоже пробовал. Но это не значит, что я не смогу получить доступ к базе, если окажусь "соседом по хостингу".

Comment: добавьте в php
`file_put_contents('test.log',var_export($_POST,true))` 
и проверьте приходит ли пост запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поясню все-таки подробнее:

```
<?php
try {
// Тут вы опубликовали атрибуты доступа к базе. Так делать не стОит.
// Поскольку на этом сайте хранятся версии редактируемого контента
// у вас остается один выход - поменять пароль (может даже и имя)
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=***;dbname=***', '***', '***' );
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$name = $_POST["name"];
$page_id = $_POST["id"];
$text_comment = $_POST["text"];

// В запросе вы возможно опечатались и вместо Commnets следует написать
// Comments. Кроме того сделаем подготовленный запрос и внедрим в него
// значения через плейсхолдеры и обработку запроса сделаем внутри блока try
try {
    $equery = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO `Commnets` 
        (`name`, `page_id`, `text_comment`) 
        VALUES 
        (:name, :page_id, :text_comment)");
    $equery->bindValue(':name', $name);
    $equery->bindValue(':page_id', $page_id);
    $equery->bindValue(':text_comment', $text_comment);
    $equery->exec();
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$records = array();
```